# Form saves double record but leaves one blank

Tags: ms-access

Anyone who can help me out to explain why it is that when I save a record on a form it creates a double record but one of them is always blank.

If you need any other information I will gladly share. I do have an attachment field on the form that send the attachment to the blank record and not the record with the actual data.

```
UserRec.AddNew
UserRec("DATECAPTURED").Value = Now
UserRec("FULLNAMES").Value = Me.cboFullNames 
UserRec("EMPLOYEENUMBER").Value = Me.txtEmpNum 
UserRec("INSTITUTENAME").Value = Me.cboInstituteName 
UserRec("COURSENAME").Value = Me.cboCourseName
UserRec("COURSENAMESUB").Value = Me.cboCourseSub 
UserRec("DATESTARTED").Value = Me.DATESTARTED 
UserRec("DATEFINISHED").Value = Me.DATEFINISHED 
UserRec("INSTRUCTOR").Value = Me.txtInstructor 
UserRec("RESULTS").Value = Me.cboResults 
UserRec("CERTIFICATEOBTAINED").Value = Me.Combo115 
UserRec.Update
```

Thank you

Comment: May be the second blank record is created by data macros.  Open the table and look for AfterInsert event.

Comment: @Santosh there is no event for that table

Comment: How do you save a record?

Comment: UserRec.AddNew
  UserRec("DATECAPTURED").Value = Now
    UserRec("FULLNAMES").Value = Me.cboFullNames
    UserRec("EMPLOYEENUMBER").Value = Me.txtEmpNum
    UserRec("INSTITUTENAME").Value = Me.cboInstituteName
    UserRec("COURSENAME").Value = Me.cboCourseName
    UserRec("COURSENAMESUB").Value = Me.cboCourseSub
    UserRec("DATESTARTED").Value = Me.DATESTARTED
    UserRec("DATEFINISHED").Value = Me.DATEFINISHED
    UserRec("INSTRUCTOR").Value = Me.txtInstructor
    UserRec("RESULTS").Value = Me.cboResults
    UserRec("CERTIFICATEOBTAINED").Value = Me.Combo115
    UserRec.Update

Comment: Thats the click event on the save button but ofcourse the code is stacked

Comment: Are any of your table fields or form combo-boxes multi-valued?

Comment: Are the form and its controls bound? Data is committed when: 1) close table/query/form; or 2) move to another record; or 3) run code to save. So if you are entering data on a bound form and then also running code to add a record, this is attempting to save the same data twice.

Comment: If form is not bound then Add record works correctly and it is code saving attachment that is at fault. It is not locating record created by the Add method. Also, embedding files in db can quickly use up Access 2GB size limit. Usually better to keep files external and save path into a text field.

Comment: I see now where my problem sits and it's because one or more records are bound to the table. Thank you all for your help